# ..didn't load Google Maps correctly... how to handle development of old site/new pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, google-maps

From my search I know what causes this. My question is that I have a website which is "grandfathered" as I understand it. The issue is that I see this problem when I am working on the site and run from localhost for testing.

I am wondering what the recommended way to deal with is... should nI get a key and use it, then replace the code in the file I compile?

Just not sure the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone looking I got no responses and ended up getting a key for development and will just publish without the key script. Seems to work, just not sure if this is really the best method.